# Asp.NET Web Api 2 Routing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a following route:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{service_name}/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { service_name = "identity", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I want this route to work only with following pattern (service name should always be identity):

```
api/identity/{anyController}/{id}
```

Now I could accomplish this by simply changing my route template to

```
routeTemplate: "api/identity/{controller}/{id}",
```

but then I would not be able to read "service_name" from `Request.GetRouteData();` since it's not named parameter.

Is there a simpler way to do this, rather than creating an ActionFilter which will filter all requests who's service name is not "Identity" in this case.

Comment: Can not understand, if you change to "api/identity/{controller}/{id}" there is not service_name))

Comment: @ElvinMammadov if you hardcode  template to `api/identity`, when you try to check service_name in the RouteData dictionary, there is no entry with `service_name` key.

Comment: But instead using Route config, you can use Attribute Routing. It is good way that Route config.

Comment: Use `RoutePrefix` attribute above your Controller. like `[RoutePrefix("api/identity")]` and then use `[Route("{id}")]` above your Action. Its make your Url like `api/identity/id?id=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `Route` attribute above the method that is affected. For example,

```
[Route("api/identity/{controller}/{id}", Order = 1)]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult DoSomethingHere(int id)
{
    // Do some magic here
}
```

Have a look at this article [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid attribute mess, but I guess it's a way to go